# Color Bar - Bar Color: How to mix colour-logic from different Indicators?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I try to set barcolor and other ways to paint the bars in TV.

A ***WaveMaster*** indicator paints bars Green if above an MA and Red if below, as shown in :
https://www.tradingview.com/script/fn1iJVeQ-Wave-Master/

Another indicator paints the bar, where the RSI is above/below some fixed horizontal levels, otherwise it paints them of another color.

The script is below:

```
//@version=4
study("RSI", overlay=true)

len   = input( 14, minval = 1, title = "RSI Length" )
src   = input( close, title = "RSI Source" ) 
up    = rma(  max( change( src ), 0 ), len )
down  = rma( -min( change( src ), 0 ), len )
rsi   = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
panic = ( rsi < 35 or rsi > 80 )  

barcolor( panic ? #DC143C : #FFA07A, offset = 0 )
```

If I put both indicators on, it happens that ( of course ) the last to be added will override the colouring of the candles and hide the other one, I don't know how to do it but I saw someone that has his charts with multiple colors on its candles ( 3 I'm sure );

I'd like to ask if you can help to have the first indicator ( the *Wave Master* ) as is, but also add another colouring, if the RSI conditions are met, that overrides the colouring of Red/Green and paints the candles in another color.

Pretty much merging the two indicators into one.

Also, if possible, in the *Wave Master*, since I have the condition if price above MA green else Red, what happens is that for newly listed assets since there's no moving avg yet, it automatically paints everything red, is there the possibility to rewrite the colouring in another way so that if there's no SMA yet, it won't apply any color, if it's not too complex maybe just paints the bars if the RSI condition is met.

```
//@version=1
study(title="Wave Master", shorttitle="Wave Master", overlay=true)
len = input(60, minval=1, title="MA Periods")
src = close
out = sma(src, len)
up = out > out[1]
down = out < out[1]
mycolor = up ? #0ea95a : down ? red : blue
plot(out  ? out :na , title="MA", color=mycolor, linewidth=3)

len1 = input(200, minval=1, title="Macro MA Periods")
src1 = close
out1 = sma(src1, len1)
up1 = out1 > out1[1]
down1 = out1 < out1[1]
mycolor1 = up1 ? #0ea95a : down1 ? #ef5350 : blue
plot(out1  ? out1 :na , title="Macro MA", color=mycolor1, linewidth=1)
barcolor(close > sma(close, len) ? #46B698 : #ED5454)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line of the RSI script with:

```
barcolor(panic ? #DC143C : na)
```

This will only color bars when RSI is OS or OB.

As for the other indicator, its source is not available, so it can't be modified.

Comment: Thank you,  now I'm able to have both indicators on and it work! Just one thing, do you think there's the possibility to merge them ? Because putting the two codes together the RSI one doesn't seem to work, it doesn't apply its colouring; maybe the barcolor function for it goes in conflict with the previous one and doesn't apply it?  Also I've updated the post with Indicator code. Thank you again !

Comment: With the source code of the other indicator, yes it would be possible to merge them. If you need help, show us the code you have tried and explain what's not working in it.